# Find same date time each next weeks until a specifc date time

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-7

Given a **start date time**, an **end date time** and a **repeat until date time** how do I find the same schedule each week until **repeat until date time** ?

For example:

```
start date time: 05-29-2012 07:35
end date time: 05-29-2012 10:27 
repeat until date: 06-19-2012 09:00
```

result would be:

```
06-05-2012 07:35 06-05-2012 10:27
06-12-2012 07:35 06-12-2012 10:27
```

Any idea how to do that in cfml ?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<cfset start_dt = "05-29-2012 07:35">
<cfset end_dt = "05-29-2012 10:27">
<cfset repeat_until = "06-19-2012 09:00">
<cfoutput>start: #start_dt#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>end: #end_dt#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>repeat until: #repeat_until#<br></cfoutput>
<cfset s_date='#DatePart("m", start_dt)#/#DatePart("d", start_dt)#/#DatePart("yyyy", start_dt)#'>
<cfoutput>#s_date#<br></cfoutput>
<cfset s_date = DateAdd("d", 7, s_date)>
<cfoutput>#s_date#<br></cfoutput>
```

Comment: What's wrong with just adding 7 days to the `start date`, saving the result, adding 7 more days, etc. until you reach the `repeat until` date?

Comment: OK. :-) You didn't answer my question, though; did you read what I wrote? The solution is there.

Comment: Issue is I dont know how to convert the date to timestamp so that I can add 7 days and format the result...

Comment: This line `<cfset DateAdd("d", 7, s_date)>` doesn't assign the return value to anything. Change it to `<cfset s_date = DateAdd("d", 7, s_date)>`, so you're actually assigning the return value. You'll also need a `while` loop to repeat the increment until you've reached (or passed) `repeat until`.

Comment: thx I've added the assignment to s_date now I'm working on the loop...

Comment: @StephaneKouakou - Not that it should make any difference with dates, but which version of CF are you using - 7, 8 *=OR=* 9 ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure to be honnest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example of expected results, it looks like you don't care about the value of `start_dt` only of `end_dt`.  So here is one way that you could make it work.  You only need one type of loop, but I've included two so that you can choose your own preference.

```
<cfset start_dt = "05-29-2012 07:35">
<cfset end_dt = "05-29-2012 10:27">
<cfset repeat_until = "06-19-2012 09:00">
<cfoutput>start: #start_dt#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>end: #end_dt#<br></cfoutput>
<cfoutput>repeat until: #repeat_until#<br></cfoutput>

<!--- FromTo loop --->
<cfset first_dt = DateAdd("d", 7, end_dt)>
<cfloop from="#first_dt#" to="#repeat_until#" index="current_dt" step="#CreateTimeSpan(7,0,0,0)#">
    <cfoutput>#DateFormat(current_dt, "mm-dd-yyyy")# #TimeFormat(current_dt, "HH:mm")#<br></cfoutput>
</cfloop>

<!--- Condition loop --->
<cfset current_dt = DateAdd("d", 7, end_dt)>
<cfloop condition="DateCompare(current_dt, repeat_until) LTE 0">
    <cfoutput>#DateFormat(current_dt, "mm-dd-yyyy")# #TimeFormat(current_dt, "HH:mm")#<br></cfoutput>
    <cfset current_dt = DateAdd("d", 7, current_dt)>
</cfloop>
```